# Already Exist Html element reuse using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

i need to reuse html element using jquery

**one.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var x=$("#combo1");
      $('#div1').append(x);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <select id="combo1">
      <option>asd</option>
    </select>
      <div id="div1">
      </div>
```

but it can't work

I have `combo1` and I need to add that same combo  will add to my `div1` at the time of page load with all data. Does anyone have an idea on how I can accomplish that task.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: That would cause to invalid markup because there will be repeations of same ids, so instead you can use className.

Comment: where is your jquery CDN links?....first add that script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html is invalid. Extract your div #div1 outside select then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nRhY3/

```
var x=$('#combo1");
```

should be

```
var x=$("#combo1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#combo1" ).clone().appendTo("#div1");
```